# Change Font colour when you click on a element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**I am trying to work out how, when I click on my "left" and "center" containers my "footertext" changes to Red and when I click on any of my containers (left right and center) it goes back to white**

My current HTML is this:

```
<p class="footertext" style="color:red">Designed by Clarke Cribb<br></p>


    <div class="container" id= "left" >
        <h1 style="color:white"><a>HAIR</a></h1>
    </div>

    <div class= "container" id= "center">
        <h1 style="color:white"><a>BEAUTY<a/></h1>
    </div>

    <div class="container" id= "right">
        <h1 style="color:white"><a>BARBERS</a></h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

**My Javascript is this:**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#left").click(function(){
            $("footertext").css("color","red");
        });
    });
</script>
```

If anyone can help I would appreciate it. Cheers. Clarke

Comment: `$("footertext").css("color","red");` should be `$(".footertext").css("color","red");` or you could do `$(this).parent().css("color","red");` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
 <script>

   $(document).ready(function(){
 $("#left,#center").click(function(){ 
  if($(".footertext").css("color") == 'rgb(255, 0, 0)')
  {
    $(".footertext").css("color","white");
  }
  else
  {
    $(".footertext").css("color","red");
  }
});
$("#right").click(function(){
  $(".footertext").css("color","white");
});
 });
</script>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Try removing #left from the second click event, as it is present in both click event. I have edited my answer for this

Comment: There is a extra div in your post, have you checked it?

Comment: Also, for starters, please specify initial color as red since white may cause the text to be invisible [assuming the background is also white]

Comment: Okay, so this works which is great! however the white colour doesn't come back when the left and center container is clicked again?

Comment: I have edited my answer that should handle your question, please have a look

Answer (score 0):

You can toggle classes.

Use the following CSS:

```
.red {
    color: red;
}
```

And change your js to:

```
$(function() {
    $("#left,#center,#right").click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('red');
    });
});
```

And then remove the inline styles on the HTML.